# Create CocoaPods library from opensource repo

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to use [DEST library](https://github.com/cheind/dest) in my iOS application. And I want to include it by CocoaPods.

Follow official tutorial I edit .podspec like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'dest'
  s.version          = 'v0.8'
  s.summary          = ' One Millisecond Deformable Shape Tracking Library'

  s.description      = <<-DESC
Deformable Shape Tracking (DEST) is a C++ library providing high performance 2D shape tracking leveraging machine learning methods. The video below shows the real-time capabilities of DEST in annotating video sequences / still images with facial landmarks.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/cheind/dest'
  s.license          = { :type => 'BSD', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'cheind' => 'christoph.heindl@gmail.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/cheind/dest.git', :tag => "v0.8" }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

  s.source_files = 'dest/Classes/**/*'

end
```

But when I run `pod lib lint` I have:

```
### Command
```

`/usr/local/bin/pod lib lint`

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

`CocoaPods : 1.1.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
    RubyGems : 2.0.14.1
        Host : Mac OS X 10.12.3 (16D32)
       Xcode : 8.3.2 (8E2002)
         Git : git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 4076e32f9f51026e071e398117df63084ee3fbae`

#### Plugins

`cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.1.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0`

#### Error

```
ArgumentError - Malformed version number string v0.8
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods-core/version.rb:52:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods-core/vendor/version.rb:199:in`new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods-core/vendor/version.rb:199:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/root_attribute_accessors.rb:31:in`version'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/linter.rb:109:in `block in check_required_attributes'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/linter.rb:108:in`each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/linter.rb:108:in `check_required_attributes'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/linter.rb:50:in`lint'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:281:in `perform_linting'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:78:in`validate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command/lib/lint.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command/lib/lint.rb:50:in`each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command/lib/lint.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in`run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/bin/pod:55:in`'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in`'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The version string should not include the 'v'. It should be '0.8', not 'v0.8'. More about the podspec version specification [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#version)